# Using Django to create static, CD held website

Tags: html, django

I've been tasked at work to create a 'website' on a CD for a client. I've made a start where basically everything is hardcoded pure html, and god how easily you forget how amazing templates are, so much freakin' boilerplate. So I would prefer to somehow create a set of linked html pages using a template system.

Is there some method of easily producing a set of linked html files (suitable for CD, i.e. no webserver) using something like Django? The project is doable by hand, but there's a lot of overhead.

Would love to hear alternative ideas as well, not set on Django, just what I'm kind of familiar with.

**Note:** Can't include any software, can't use anything from the internet. Flat html, on the cd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in a static-site generator like [Hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde) (Python) or [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) (Ruby). Essentially lets you create pages in Markdown/Textile/whatever with templates, and then generate static HTML files with a simple shell command. You can deploy it however you want, since it's just files.

I've used Jekyll myself because I heard about it first (despite being a Python guy primarily), but Hyde seems a bit more competent (CSS processors, for example). Jekyll is more widely used, I think.

(Using Django would mean that you'd have to run a Django installation on *some* server just to create the content and then generate "linked html files"...)

Comment: I should also note there is now a new site for the [hyde project](http://hyde.github.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach: http://lethain.com/intricate-static-websites-with-django-templates/